# Let $A$ be a ring. If $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is a finite set, then $A$ is a noetherian ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$A$ : commutative with unit

$\operatorname{Spec} A$ is finite $\Rightarrow$ $A$ has finitely many maximal ideals $ = \{M_1, M_2, ..., M_n\} $

If $ I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq...\subseteq I_n \subseteq...$ with every $I_j \subseteq M$, $M$  is a maximal ideal of $A$.

Can this imply this ascending chain is stationary?

Comment: There are non-noetherian local rings, so you would need something more from the assumptions than just finitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]_{(x_1,x_2,\ldots)}$. This ring has one maximal ideal but is not Noetherian. Thus, it is not enough to use that there are finitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: Spec$\,A$ generally denotes the set of **prime** ideals of $A$,

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to typeset $\operatorname{Spec}$: this produces the best spacing.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your advice. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider $A=k[x_1,x_2,\cdots]/(x_1,x_2,\cdots)^2$. This has a unique prime ideal $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$, so $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is a single point. On the other hand, $A$ is not Noetherian since this ideal is not finitely generated.

Comment: In this case, is Spec $A$ a finite set ?

Comment: $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is one point. I've edited for clarity.

Comment: How does one see $(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is the only prime ideal? It seems like $A$ is effectively all linear polynomials in infinitely many variables, with the relation $x_ix_j=0$ for any $i,j$. Why isn't something like $(x_1+x_2)$ also prime in $A$?

Comment: @AdelaideDokras The nilradical of a ring is contained in every prime ideal. Every polynomial with no constant term in $A$ is nilpotent (it squares to zero), so all prime ideals must contain $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. On the other hand, $A/(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\cong k$, so by the correspondence theorem there are no proper ideals containing $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. So this is the unique prime ideal.

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NEMO After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).